# Find data's (.txt)'s from another directory and save the name in a list

Tags: python, linux, shell

I need a command in Python to find a data (txt) somewhere on my computer.

I wish I could give you example code, but I have none.

Comment: Have a look at [find](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html#examples)

Comment: i will try it thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the path to the directory containing the txt files, you can use `glob`:

```
import glob
file_list = glob.glob("<path_to_your_directory>/*.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to run a Linux [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command on a directory and collect the files ending with *.txt*:

```
from subprocess import check_output

# shell command
# remove -printf "%f\n" if you want full paths to files
command = 'find <PATH> -type f -name *.txt -printf "%f\n"'

# get contents returned from command
command_str = check_output(command, shell=True).decode('utf-8')

# split string on newlines to get list of filenames
files = command_str.split()
```

Where `<PATH>` is the relative/absolute path to your directory containing the files.

**Note:** Since `check_output()` encodes your content in [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes), you need to use [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) to decode it to a string instead. Then you can split this string to collect the filenames into a list.

If you want to find out more about `find`, type `man find` into the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `os`, `shlex` and `subprocess` combined to achieve this:

```
import os
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
import shlex

#Change directory to where you want to start looking
os.chdir("the_path_from where_you_want_to_start_looking")

#Shell command for searching for .txt files
command = 'find . -name "*.txt"'

#Run command in shell
args = shlex.split(command)
process = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

#Get output of command
result = process.communicate()[0]

#result is bytes object so need to parse it to list
list_of_files = str(result).replace("b'", "").split("\\n")

#list_of_files will be desired list
```

Hope this helps.